# Vagrant Symbolic Links in shared folder: work only in same dir (Windows host)

Tags: windows, ubuntu, vagrant, virtualbox, symlink

I run my `Vagrant 1.7.4` with `VirtualBox 5.0.1 r102010` on `Windows 10`, my guest os is `Ubuntu 12.04.5`.

AFIK, symlinks are not allowed by default in shared folders on Windows.

So I added this instruction to my `Vagrantfile`

```
config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
    v.customize ["setextradata", :id,   "VBoxInternal2/SharedFoldersEnableSymlinksCreate/v-root", "1"]
end
```

Also I started Vagrant with Admin privileges.

It helped partially: I can create link in my shared folder root, but only in same dir, for example, I have directory `/vagrant/provision`

And this works:

`ln -sn provision myLink`

But when I try to change path, even like this

`ln -sn ./provision myLink`

It would not work: broken "red" link is created and it does not lead anywhere.
The same when I try to create link

This woks as well

`ln -sn provision ./myLink`

but not this

`ln -sn provision ./subdir/myLink`

Is there a solution for that?

[image]

**UPD**: Looks like it is VirtualBox and Windows 10 issue, with last update VB 5.0.3 i can create links, specifying full path for target object.

Comment: I am experiencing a similar issue, but I am on OSX Host with Virtual Box 5.0.4.  Could you reference where you found the extra information in the update ?

Comment: I just installed new beta, that's it. Actually I have OSX as well and I do not have any such problems on that platform.